# How to manipulate static files served from IIS7

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, http, iis-7

I have an ASP.net MVC site where I also serve some static html, js and css files from a virtual directory. Depending on the user agent of the request I want to manipulate the static html files when they are served (it is not an option to use a razor view - I need to work in the static files). Do you write an HttpHandler og an HttpModule or is there some StaticHttpHandler events that one can hook in to ?

Comment: Are you wanting users to edit/upload existing files, or just modify what is there? Or are you meaning that you want the server to automatically manage the changes based on some other criteria/elapsed period of time? Or, finally, are you looking to accept API/RPC commands of sort to direct the server to make certain types of changes to the files, and will those be accepting parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a normal controller and action. Map the appropriate route(s) to that action. You can do whatever you want in that action including reading a file, modifying the data and returning it to the HTTP client.